# is it possible to do static routing in a peer to peer network?

Tags: routing

I was wondering if its possible that in a p2p network; for example, Gnutella, that one node could establish a static routing with another node. I know that in a p2p network each node acts like a client and a server, so that figure would be possible

In summary, I would like to know if in this type of networks ,a node would be able to sent a message by passing through some other specific node,  by using static routing, before reaching its destination.

Comment: This has nothing to do with *routing*. It's up to the messaging protocol to handle this type of forwarding. (google SMTP and smarthost)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Routing is a layer-3 function.  An application, like Gnutella, happens at a higher layer which uses layer-4 for the end-to-end connection.  Routing is independent of the application.  Certainly, there is probably static routing between such applications, but the application is unaware of the routes used.

Having said that, new technologies (e.g. SDN) will allow the application to have more say in how routing happens.

Comment: Most applications are completely unaware of any SDN. And SDN cannot influence anything beyond it's realm (i.e. data center.)

Comment: @RickyBeam, as of today, that is correct, but some SDN vendors have some experimental stuff that does allow an application to have some say in its routing. That's why I used the word "will". It isn't happening in production today, but I'm pretty sure it is coming. It's not actually something I look forward to.